# fitnesse hangs in fitnesse.testrunner.MultipleTestsRunner.waitForTestSystemToSendResults

Tags: fitnesse

In approximately 1 of 10 of our fitnesse test runs running headless (from cmd line, not in browser) the run hangs in `fitnesse.testrunner.MultipleTestsRunner.waitForTestSystemToSendResults`

We ensured with using listeners and console output that all tests that were announced to run are completed. We used the following methods to ensure that:
`fitnesse.testrunner.TestsRunnerListener.announceNumberTestsToRun(int)` and `fitnesse.testsystems.TestSystemListener.testComplete(PageType, TestSummary)`

So our tests always hang after the last test of the suite was executed. The wait is done until a volatile member `int testsInProgressCount` is decreased to 0 but this does not seem to happen.

Does anybody have similar issues with fitnesse or any idea what is the reason or a good idea how to troubleshoot the issue?

Some more information:

- Fitnesse version: **20150814**
- Platform: Linux centos 6.5 (kernel is 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64)
- Cmdline (simplified): `java -cp <CLASSPATH> -r fitnesse -c <TestSuiteName>?suite&format=xml&includehtmlFalse -b OutFile  -p <PORT> fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain`
- using 1.8

Comment: Maybe you can include a bit more detail? For instance: which version of FitNesse, which test system (if Slim, in which language), on which platform?  What do you mean exactly when running headless: how did you start the tests exactly?

Comment: I added some more information to the description. Not sure which test system we use. I think it is `fitnesse.testsystems.fit.FitTestSystem` which might be default. Not sure where you specify that!? Thanks for looking having a look.